# Abort calling "complete:" callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
    $(function() {
        (function poll(){
            var update_progress = setTimeout(function(){
                    var jxhr = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "grab.php",
                        data: "test",
                        success: function(data){
                            var error = data.error;

                            if(error == false) {
                                // My nonsense is here
                            } else if(error == true) {
                                // Stop sending AJAX request
                                clearTimeout(update_progress);
                                jxhr.abort();
                            }

                        }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 2000 });
            }, 2000);
        })()
    });
```

As you can see i try to abort calling the "complete:" callback once again if my script returns an error, and also i clear the timeout.

So basicly it should not do any ajax request anymore. However it still does. What did i wrong?

Comment: you can't abort a request that is already complete. there's nothing you can do here aside from having a global flag that you set to false in the success, then in complete abort if it's false.

Comment: That is just logical ^^ I just want to stop further requests.

Comment: Right, but that's the logic. YOu have to cancel using a flag of some kind.

Comment: @KevinB is right and also clearTimeout is meanless here

Comment: Could one of you please psot a code example? I am very new to javascript/jquery and try to it as good as i can. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
$(function() {
    (function poll(){
        var keepPolling = true;
        var update_progress = setTimeout(function(){
                var jxhr = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "grab.php",
                    data: "test",
                    success: function(data){
                        var error = data.error;

                        if(error == false) {
                            // My nonsense is here
                        } else if(error == true) {
                            // Stop sending AJAX request
                            keepPolling = false;
                        }

                    }, dataType: "json", complete: function() {
                        if (keepPolling) {
                            poll();
                        }
                    }, timeout: 2000 });
        }, 2000);
    })()
});
```

Basically, have an extra var that tracks if you want to continue polling.  Default it to true and set to false when you get an error.  Then in the complete method you check if you want to keep polling before actually calling poll again.

I'm not sure if complete or success is called first.  If complete is called first then this won't work (though you could probably add the keepPolling check at the top of the function passed to setTimeout).

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for the explanation. I am very new to javascript/jquery, so this helps me alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
complete - A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and
error callbacks are executed).
```

So no matter what you do in your `success` handler `poll()` will **always** be called. The simplest solution would be

```
if(error == false) {
  ...
  poll();
}
else {
  //don't poll ;) and forget clearTimeout and abort as it's useless
```

On more thing: I case of an error your script should return the proper Http status code (some 4xx or 5xx). Then you can put your error handling code into a proper `error` handler instead of the `success` handler.